# Name for the result of characterizing isomorphism of linear mapping between vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

Let $V, W$ be two finite dimensional vector spaces and $E = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ the basis of $V$. I do know that $T:V \to W$ is an isomorphism if and only if the image $T[E]$ is a basis for $W$. But is there a generally accepted common name for this property? That is, if I am writing  a proof, could I say

> ...by characterization of isomorphism between finite dimensional vector spaces,...

or does there exists a specific name for this property?

Comment: I think this property is so easy to check that it was never given a common name. You could simply write "because $T:V\to W$ is an isomorphism if and only if $T[E]$ is a basis for $W$...."

Comment: In the context of abstract algebra, the generalization of this fact is referred to as the "universal property of free modules". I don't know a common name for this property in the context of linear algebra, though